# Custom Video Controls In Full Screen Mode

Tags: html, css, video, custom-controls, fullscreen

As anybody know how to manipulate position and attributes of existing video control in html-html5?
I'd like to simply change the position of the controls when in full screen mode but i cant't find any issue the explain how to do that.

If not possible i read about costumising the controls, it's possible to costomising also controls in fullscreen? how?
this is an exemple but in firefox it works bad and the fullscreen is not costomised... http://www.inwebson.com/demo/html5-video/demo1/

thank to everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.videojs.com/

here is a very good plugin, it's possible to customise the thumbnail mode and the full screen mode separately... the best one i've find!

compliments to video.js and i hope this question could help someone else in future ;)